# how to make android gridView of showing multiple columns

Tags: android

i have XML file in the internet i parse it and get arrayList of Strings represents URL of images i need to create grid view of these images dynamically.
my problem is when i am trying to display these images in the grid view they are displayed as one column.i do not know how to fix this.
here the ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Serializable mThumbIds ;
ImageDownLoader imageDownloader;
private String img_url;
int item_id;
ConnectorInterface _conn=new ConnectorImpl();

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}
public ImageAdapter(Context c,Serializable a){
    mContext=c;
    mThumbIds= a;
}



public int getCount() {
    return ((ArrayList<ItemEntity> )mThumbIds).size();

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
   return item_id;
}

// create a new ImageView for each items referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = null ;
    for (int x=0;x<((ArrayList<ItemEntity>) mThumbIds).size();x++){
         imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    if (convertView == null) {

        imageDownloader = new ImageDownLoader(imageView);

            imageDownloader.execute(((ArrayList<ItemEntity>) mThumbIds).get(x).getThumbnailImg());

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(50,50));
           imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
         imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

}

i need help plz;

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the number of columns in grid with the following attribute in xml.

```
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

at the place of auto_fit give some number

Comment: i already did it but no way.when i specify number it dublicates the same image returned by the adapter.i thiink i have issue in how to loop and retun from the adapter